# In Postgres, can logical replication changes from separate transactions share the same LSN?

Tags: postgresql, cdc, logical-replication

If so, in what scenarios will they share the same LSN?

To demonstrate, here's a simplified example of a sequence of logical replication changes:

```
LSN: 03
type: create
data: {
  pk_id: 123,
  column_1: foo
}

---

LSN: 02
type: delete
data: {
  pk_id: 123,
  column_1: bar
}
```

By observing the LSN (which is monotonically increasing), we can conclude that `123` was first deleted, then re-created. But is it possible to encounter these changes sharing the same LSN? ie:

```
LSN: 02
type: create
data: {
  pk_id: 123,
  column_1: foo
}
---
LSN: 02
type: delete
data: {
  pk_id: 123,
  column_1: bar
}
```

Since they have the same LSN, determining which event occurred first is trickier. But is this sequence even possible? I believe this can only occur if multiple transactions can share the same LSN.

If this is possible, how likely will multiple transactions have the same LSN? I believe there's also a "postgres commit timestamp in milliseconds" on each logical change, so maybe I can leverage that to break ties when the LSN is the same. But I'm not sure if it's reasonable to rely on that.

For context, I'm processing the [logical replication changes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) emitted through a [Postgres publication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html). Due to external constraints, I can't assume the changes I'm processing are in chronological order (let's assume they were dumped into a queue, unordered). So I'm planning to rely on the LSN's monotonicity to order them. But before I do, I want to understand the trade-offs and edge cases.

Comment: Duplicate LSN does not appear possible `"Log Sequence Number (LSN) that is a byte offset into the logs, increasing monotonically with each new record"` See [30.6. WAL Internals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-internals.html)

Comment: I don't think this is an issue of a duplicate LSN, but rather having changes across multiple transactions sharing the same LSN. Multiple logical changes can be grouped under the same LSN. For example, I've seen logical changes for different rows share the same LSN. But I want to know if multiple logical changes for the _same_ row can share the same LSN.

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe that the "record", used in the phrase "each new record" in that doc above, is referring to a WAL record and not a row in the database. I don't think the LSN has to be increased for each row that changes.

Comment: I got you now. However, I read the doc a little different. At the core of replication is the WAL. While the schemes vary for performance and availability and can be put together in different ways, they all refer to the Write Ahead Log for what took place. The LSN refers to a particular point in the log. It being analogized to a "pointer", providing the location for a particular entry. What is getting lost is that the LSN is a 64-bit integer printed in two (up to) 8-hex digits parts. I'm no expert, but I think the part you are referring to is just the 1st part -- which would be non-unique.

Comment: Description above from [8.20. pg_lsn Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pg-lsn.html)